# about NVD3.js, How to delete .nv-context in LinePlusBarChart

Tags: charts, nvd3.js

I user NVD3.js to creat a "Line Plus Bar Chart",

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPXQs.png)

but I don't need the thing(class->.nv-context) on the bottom(I don't know how to describe it) how can I remove it?

Comment: Looks like you have multiple series?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by adding this to the nv model :

```
yournvmodel.focusEnable(false)
```